# Stopping a timer in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

From what I can tell, the timer being called in a different scope.. how can I accomplish a function to stop the timer?  Going a bit crazy here, thank you for any help.

```
const SomeComponent = ({ isPlaying }) => {
  let timer = null;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      startTimer();
    }
  },[isPlaying]);

  const startTimer = () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('tick');
    }, 1000);
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    console.log('stopping timer: ', timer);  // shows null, instead of giving the timerId to stop properly
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timer` variable will "reset" each time your component is re-rendered. Even if it holds your timer, a re-render will set its value to `null` again.

You could either move out of  the component scope, or use `useRef` to keep the variable through re-renders:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ isPlaying }) => {
  const timer = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      startTimer();
    }

    return () => clearInterval(timer.current);
  }, [isPlaying]);

  const startTimer = () => {
    timer.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('tick');
    }, 1000);
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
  };
```

Note that I also force a `clearInterval` by using a return inside the useEffect. This way the component will automatically "clean up" when it unmounts. I also changed `timer` to be a constant.

Comment: ahhh useRef!!  thank you!  going to try right now. been stuck on this for hours now.

Comment: is the "return () => clearInterval(timer.current);" supposed to be like a component unmount?  experimenting with functional Components at the moment and that was my next topic of research.  thank you

Comment: Yes, sort of. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1. It will run when the component unmounts but *also* when the effect runs again, which is when `isPlaying` changes. If you want it *only* on unmount, you could add some logic in the return function.

Comment: Why is there another clearInterval function at the bottom? Wouldn't the cleanup function be enough?

Comment: @captaincustard, it would. But since OP had a function to specifically cancel the timer, I added such function as well. Perhaps to cancel the timer on some user interaction, such as a click or something. Who knows.